# nestjs graphql : HTTP request in resolver is hanging

Tags: javascript, rest, graphql, nestjs

I'm adding the graphql endpoint to my nestjs server.
The rest api of this server is working fine.
The idea is to host in the same server the rest and graphql version of my fonctions.

For auth tasks (login, check JWT, logout,..) , the nestjs server is calling an external api , using Axios to perform a HTTP GET request. The result of the request validates that user is auth or not.

The AuthService is working well when calling it from the AuthGuard that protects the endpoints of the controller. I'm using Postman to test this REST controller.
The AuthService is executing the HTTP Request and get the response from the external API. No issue at all.

However, when the same AuthService is called from a graphql resolver, the HTTP request executed is stucked and after several minutes, it failed in timeout. I'm using the playground to perform the test the gql queries

Wondering why the HTTP GET request is fine when it is called from a REST controller, whereas this request is stucked when called from a gal resolver.

To avoid any unnecessary discussions, if I remove the HTTP call in the `checkme` function in the `AuthController` and send directly back `true` or `false` to mock the authentication, all is woking well on both REST and GraphQL. So the problem is really related to the Axios HTTP GET call `await this.authClient.get("/me",{...})`

Also, I have other GQL mutations and queries in the same module that ara running well. So I guess that the graphql parameters are correct in nestjs

Below part of the code

**AUTH SERVICE (`checkme` function that calls the `/me` endpoint of external API)**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
constructor(@Inject(EAuthProviders.AUTH_CLIENT) private readonly authClient: AxiosInstance) {}


async checkme(request: Request): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
      
    await this.authClient.get("/me", { // <--- this call to external api is stucked when the graphql provider executes the checkme function
        baseUrl : "https://localhosts/auth",
        method: "GET",
        headers: request.headers,
      }); 

     return true
 
    } catch { return false    }
  }
}
```

**AUTH RESOLVER, checkme function is called but stucks when reaching the external call**

```
@Resolver(() => AuthObjectType)
export class AuthResolver {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}

  @Query(() => Boolean)
  async isAuth(@Context() ctx: { req: Request }): Promise<boolean> {
    const a = await this.authService.checkme(ctx.req);
    return a;
  }
}
```

**AUTH GUARD  (same `checkme` function called, no issue at all)**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const r = context.switchToHttp().getRequest() as Request;

    try {
      const resu = await this.authService.checkme(r);
      return true;
    } catch {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

**GQLPLAYGROUND parameters**

```
{
  "editor.cursorShape": "line",
  "editor.fontFamily": "'Source Code Pro', 'Consolas', 'Inconsolata', 'Droid Sans Mono', 'Monaco', monospace",
  "editor.fontSize": 14,
  "editor.reuseHeaders": true,
  "editor.theme": "dark",
  "general.betaUpdates": false,
  "prettier.printWidth": 80,
  "prettier.tabWidth": 2,
  "prettier.useTabs": false,
  "request.credentials": "include",
  "schema.disableComments": true,
  "schema.polling.enable": true,
  "schema.polling.endpointFilter": "*localhost*",
  "schema.polling.interval": 2000,
  "tracing.hideTracingResponse": true,
  "queryPlan.hideQueryPlanResponse": true
}
```

Comment: you are not catching error in catch.  Try see what's the error is, you can also log that error, or throw it

Comment: I do (not in the example but in real code). And there is no error thrown... Process is stuck. Error is raised after 3 or 4 minutes when the graphql playground closed the transaction with a timeout

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the issue, that was (as usual) a very stupid one.
In order to pass the token received from the client headers (here PostMan or the GQL playground), I "copied-pasted" the client headers to the call to the external API. Big mistake :

```
await this.authClient.get("/me", { 
        method: "GET",
        headers: request.headers,  // <--- stupid error HERE !
      });
```

Have just changed the call as follows, and all is fine now:

```
await this.authClient.get("/me", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Authorization: request.headers.authorization ? request.headers.authorization : `bearer ${this._accessToken}`,
        },
      });
```